# Git won't update a directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a nicely functioning git repo on Bitbucket.org.
However I have one directory that doesn't seem to be under my repo's control.

Whenever I push changes, anything in that directory is left behind. If I clone the repo into a new location, that directory shows up, but it's empty.

I think the directory contents were lifted from another project, probably in another git repo (I'm not the one coding this particular little bit of the project) - perhaps that's connected?

When I view the listing of this section of the repo in Bitbucket, that directory displays thus:
commerce_shipworks → eb549bd63c0b [eb549bd63c0b]

Does this mean it's pointing to some other branch that I am not connected to?
Bottom line - how can I regain control of this batch of code?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Was the directory path added into a .gitignore file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is a submodule, or "accidental" submodule.

Is there `.gitmodule` file?

If not, it's likely an accidental submodule, meaning where somebody did a `git clone` into a subdirectory, and didn't remove the `.git` folder.

From this [website](http://humansky.com/2011/12/accidentally-adding-a-git-submodule/):

> Here is what you need to do in order to remove the submodule and add
>   as a subfolder:

```
git rm --cached subfolder
git add subfolder
git commit -m "Enter message here"
git push
```

> Now the origin should be able to see the contents of the subfolder.

Comment: that was the clue, thanks.
For the benefit of others reading this - I had to do 
git rm --cached commerce_shipworks from one level up, then add the folder back in as per directions.
That still didn't get Bitbucket to wake up; I went into my stage site, deleted the folder entirely after git pull complained:, and then did git pull again; at that point Bitbicket started treating the directory normally.